# How to remove particular Billing Address Field?

Tags: magento

I'm newbie on magneto. I want to remove **Billing Address Field**, For example  `Middle Name/Initial`.

when Go to Magento Admin Panel. In Admin Panel **Sales** ->**Orders** and **Create New order** and **select customer**. **In Billing Address section**. I want to remove red portion according to following image.

Please see my [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYz37.png).

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/middle-name-in-billing-shipping-name-backend-mail/49738#49738

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

*Middle Name / Initials* field can be removed from admin panel.

Go to `System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options > Show Middle Name (initial)` and set value to `No`.

**Important**: There is a know bug of *Middle Name / Initials* field shown even after setting value is set to `No`. To fix it, set value to `Yes`, save settings and than set it back to `No` and save it.

Bug most commonly occurs when Magento is updated to version *Magento CE 1.9.2.1* and later.